# PHP - Manipulate user picture in active directory

Tags: php, active-directory

Is it possible to retrieve and update a user's picture in Active Directory using PHP? If so, how would this be accomplished?

Here is my setup:

- PHP 5.3 on IIS 7.5
- Domain controller is Windows 2008

i told about it [pictures-in-active-directory](http://www.moe.am/index.php/2009/03/pictures-in-active-directory-users-and-computers/)

Comment: Please add more context. What system is your PHP running, where is your AD server.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the user image is stored inside the Active Directory by default. User images are stored in the user profile and not in the Active Directory.

It is possible to extend the Active Directory schema to include images, but they are not used for the user image when logging in for example.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory exposes the jpegPhoto attribute for this, see the following links:

- [Using the jpegPhoto attribute in AD](http://blogs.technet.com/b/btrst4/archive/2004/08/30/222629.aspx)
- [jpegPhoto Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676813%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)